# How to clear textboxes and send alert message using Ajax if the data can't be found in MySQL table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to clear the textboxes and send an alert message when the data can't be found inside the MySQL table. Is there a way to do this even I use the type: 'json'? Because when I tried to remove json, the alert message is working, problem is if I do this it doesn't show the data inside MySQL table.
Thank you in advance for the help.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').click(function() {
    var inp = $('#username');
    if (inp.val().length > 0) {
      var src_uname = $('#username').val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "./search_process.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          username: src_uname
        },

        success: function(data) {
  
          var fullname = data[0]['fullname'];
          var address = data[0]['address'];

          document.getElementById('fullname').value = fullname;
          document.getElementById('address').value = address;

        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("Enter username in the textbox!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form_data" style="width:40%;margin:1em auto;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" />
    <input type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-success" value="Search" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" class="form-control" placeholder="Fullname" />
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" />
  </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php
$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testdb");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblajax WHERE username = '$username' ";
$result = mysqli_query($cn,$query);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$info_arr = array();

if ($numrows > 0 ) {
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $fullname = $rows['fullname'];
        $address = $rows['address'];

        $info_arr[] = array("fullname" => $fullname, "address" => $address);
    }

}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Unable to find the information');</script>";
}
    echo json_encode($info_arr);
    exit;
?>
```

I want to send this alert message if the data can't be found:

```
echo "<script>alert('Unable to find the information');</script>";
```

And also I want to clear these two textboxes if the data can't be found:

```
<input type = "text" id = "fullname" name = "fullname" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Fullname" />
<input type = "text" id = "address" name = "address" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Address" />
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: I'll vote this question as **too broad**. Hint: Either give a valid JSON response with an error code or set a response error header. Try it on your own and come back with an approach of a custom error handling. Implementing an application layer protocol is up to the coder.

Comment: see the `console.log(data)` in success block .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to return a "success" status in your JSON. Then you can check that on the client side and alert a message as required. So you could change your code like this:

PHP

```
if ($numrows > 0 ) {
    $info_arr['data'] = array();
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $fullname = $rows['fullname'];
        $address = $rows['address'];

        $info_arr['data'][] = array("fullname" => $fullname, "address" => $address);
    }
    $info_arr['success'] = true;
}
else {
    $info_arr = array('success' => false);
}
echo json_encode($info_arr);
exit;
```

jQuery:

```
success: function(data) {

  if (data.success) {
      var fullname = data.data[0]['fullname'];
      var address = data.data[0]['address'];
      document.getElementById('fullname').value = fullname;
      document.getElementById('address').value = address;
  }
  else {
      document.getElementById('fullname').value = '';
      document.getElementById('address').value = '';
      alert('Unable to find the information');
  }
}
```

Comment: It works great! :) Thank you very much :) I just added these at the bottom of the alert  message to clear the textboxes: document.getElementById('fullname').value = " ";
document.getElementById('address').value = " ";

Comment: @CodeSurfer sorry I skipped that requirement to clear the text boxes. But what you have done is the way to do it. I've added that code to my answer for anyone else that sees this question.

Comment: one quick question if you don't mind, where this piece of code came from? 
if (data.success) , is this came from $info_arr['success'] = true; ? Thank you, I just want to learn how you did it :)

Comment: @CodeSurfer that's exactly right. By adding associative keys to the array in PHP, the value in javascript becomes an object with those keys. So in both branches of the `if` in the PHP we add a `success` element to the array, and then we can access that in javascript as data.success. This is also why the data is accessed as data.data (sorry the naming was a bit confusing!) because it refers to the `data` element of the `$info_arr` array.

Answer (score 0):

You should send another HTTP status on fail, e.g. 404

```
if ($numrows > 0 ) {
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $fullname = $rows['fullname'];
        $address = $rows['address'];

        $info_arr[] = array("fullname" => $fullname, "address" => $address);
    }

}
else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

and use below in JS, similar to the success event

```
success: function(data) {
          //var len = data.length;

          //if(len > 0){

          var fullname = data[0]['fullname'];
          var address = data[0]['address'];

          document.getElementById('fullname').value = fullname;
          document.getElementById('address').value = address;

          //}

        },
error: function() {
   document.getElementById('fullname').value = '';
   document.getElementById('address').value = '';

   alert ('Unable to find the information');
}
```

or check in success: function()`whether`data[0]['fullname'];` exists

```
if (data[0]['fullname']) {
//do fill fields
} else {
 document.getElementById('fullname').value = '';
 document.getElementById('address').value = '';

 alert ('Unable to find the information');
}
```